# Moshi deserializing values as null

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, retrofit2, moshi

I've recently switched from Gson to Moshi and am having trouble parsing some Json.

```
{
  "access_token": "-LNe2LQ7DQH5Y2zs_W5iUumKuaUE",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "device_id": "461f-837e-af5050c92fe9",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "*"
}
```

And here's the model class:

```
data class AuthToken(
        @Json(name = "access_token") val accessToken: String,
        @Json(name = "token_type") val tokenType: String,
        @Json(name = "device_id") val deviceId: String,
        @Json(name = "expires_in") val expiresIn: Int,
        @Json(name = "scope") val scope: String
)
```

Whenever I switch to using Moshi in my retrofit client, I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull
```

I have made the field nullable, however it is always deserialized as null. I've checked my retrofit response and it's (obviously) the same when using either Gson or Moshi. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, when I explicitly tell the `AuthToken` class to generate an adapter - I receive no null values.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AuthToken(
        @Json(name = "access_token") val accessToken: String,
        @Json(name = "token_type") val tokenType: String,
        @Json(name = "device_id") val deviceId: String,
        @Json(name = "expires_in") val expiresIn: Int,
        @Json(name = "scope") val scope: String
)
```

Comment: If you don't use Moshi's Kotlin support (the reflective KotlinJsonAdapterFactory or codegen adapters), the `@Json` names are not read correctly. (They are not added to the field, and the default reflective Java adapter doesn't see them.)